# Google Drive API create temporary download link to any file

Tags: php, google-drive-api

For any given file in a google drive account, I want to be able to generate a temporary universal download link. This download link should only last a certain amount of time, and anyone with the link should be able to download the file. I've tried getWebContentLink() and getDownloadUrl() but both don't allow just anybody to download the file. I was hoping for a function similar to dropbox where you could just generate a temporary link for any file.

Any suggestions?
I am using the php google drive api

```
$downloadUrl = $file->getWebContentLink();
$downloadUrl = $file->getDownloadUrl();
```

Comment: try simply changing the file permission to public, then revert it. the link would be the same link to the file

Comment: how would you revert it? I understand how to change the file permission, but there doesn't seem to be a function to revert it

Comment: Check this url on how to remove permissions: https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2494893?hl=en